# Whats wrong with my reply-url for AAD auth?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I am trying to use AAD auth in my app, it works fine when I run it locally in VS and I can login, but when I publish it to a azure appservice and try to access the application I get the error message that the reply-to URL does not match.

Here is my appsettings.json part

```
 "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "xxxxx.me",
    "TenantId": "xxxxx",
    "ClientId": "xxxx",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": "xxxxx",
    "AppIDURL": "https://xxxxx.me/yyyyyBackend",
    "ConfigView": "MVC"
```

In the app registration I have added the reply-URL which is the app URL from the appservice, I have also added

```
https://xxxxx.me/yyyyyBackend/signin-oidc
```

but neither works so I am a bit confused now

Is there another reply-URL I have to add?

*** EDIT ***

After using fiddler and also looking at the callback URL when the applictions tries to auth it turns out that it sends the following redirect URL

```
https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback
```

No where in my project have I specified /.auth/login/aad/callback and if I search through my entire project in VS that string does not show up anywhere, so I am at total loss as to why it sends that redirect URL? It will never work because I dont have that anywhere in my code

After adding that URL to my reply-url in the appservice I am getting the following error message when deploying

```
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
```

Comment: What's your Web App home page URL? Could you post which sample do you refer to ? Generally, the reply url should be `<the Home page URL of your App>/signin-oidc`

Comment: In Azure portal go to Azure AD -> App registrations then click on the app in question and it has a Home Page property there, that's what I am referring to

Comment: The home page shouldn't just be there. You should look into the Web App directly. E.g. Where do you web App publish? The Home page should just be the URL of your Web App.

Comment: I publish to azure app service and that's the URL it assigns to my app

Comment: So, The reply url should be like `https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc` if the URL of your Azure web App is `https://xxx.azurewebsites.net`

Comment: yes and I have that added and I still get the error message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171608/discussion-between-wayne-yang-msft-and-matt-douhan).

Comment: I am lost for words, if I go into Azure portal AppServices and turn OFF authentication for my app, then everything works, and I MUST authenticate even if it is turned OFF, I don't even know what to say, I deleted the app and recreated it and its the same thing, totally reproducable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to your description, I assumed that you are using OpenID Connect middleware to sign-in users from AAD tenant, here is the detailed tutorial [Integrating Azure AD into an ASP.NET Core web app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore). For running in your local side, you may add the following reply url for your AAD app:

```
http(s)://localhost:{port}/signin-oidc
```

When deployed to azure web app, you may also need to add the following URL as Wayne Yang - MSFT commented:

```
https://{your-webapp-name}.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc
```

> After using fiddler and also looking at the callback URL when the applictions tries to auth it turns out that it sends the following redirect URL
>
> https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback

Based on your update, you also enable the built-in [Authentication and authorization in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview) which helps you sign in users and access data by writing minimal or no code in your MVC application. For your situation, since you have used OpenID Connect middleware in your application for authentication, you need to disable App Service Authentication, otherwise you may encounter unexpected errors.

Moreover, for troubleshooting the detailed error, you could [Enable diagnostics logging for web apps in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log).

Comment: That was it, I had both enabled, when I disable the app service auth everything works as expected, leads me to ask however when should I use the app service one and when should I not?

Comment: When hosting your web application via web app, I would prefer choose the built-in App Service Authentication without adding authentication middleware in my code. But if you host application outside of azure app service, you could not leverage this feature, you may need to manually add the authentication middleware in your code. When enabling authentication in your code, you could get better flexibility and you could programmatically initialize the authentication settings.

Comment: Cool, so how do you call sql server with user-specific AD authentication if you are using app service built in auth?