# signin-oidc vs aad/callback

Tags: azure-active-directory, identity, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to implement AAD authentication for a server side blazor app. I've created the project from a VS2019 template, selecting .Net 5 and Microsoft Identity.

In the course of trying to make things work, I've actually created the site several times. I've noticed that sometimes it wants to redirect to *azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc* and other times to *azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback*

Can anyone explain why? I guess it comes down to a different version of the code that gets executed in *ConfigureServices*? My current code is:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
            services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
                options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
            });

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
```

Comment: Can you please check this Discussions it might help you: 1)https://forums.asp.net/t/2155544.aspx?AAD+REPLY+URL+issue+signin+oidc+vs+auth+login+aad+callback+Azure+Government+  . 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483483/whats-wrong-with-my-reply-url-for-aad-auth

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw-MT thank you - that's the same problem

Comment: I have observed this same behaviour. I ended adding both Redirect URI:
OAuth2 middleware: `/.auth/login/aad/callback`
OpenID connect middleware: `/signin-oidc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank You [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41169/rob-bowman) for confirming the same problem. Updating the answer over here to help other community member as well.

When you deploy your local app to azure web app. you need to add the following as reply URL.

```
https://{your-webapp-name}.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc
```

> SO, The reply url should be like
> https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc if the URL of your Azure web
> App is https://xxx.azurewebsites.net

As Posted in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483483/whats-wrong-with-my-reply-url-for-aad-auth) thread by “author” : [Bruce Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6755924/bruce-chen)

> you also enable the built-in [Authentication and authorization in
> Azure App
> Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview)
> which helps you sign in users and access data by writing minimal or no
> code in your MVC application. For your situation, since you have used
> OpenID Connect middleware in your application for authentication, you
> need to disable App Service Authentication, otherwise you may
> encounter unexpected errors.
>
> Moreover, for troubleshooting the detailed error, you could [Enable
> diagnostics logging for web apps in Azure App
> Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log).
>
> **Note**: When hosting your web application via web app, prefer  to choose
> the built-in App Service Authentication without adding authentication
> middleware in my code. But if you host application outside of azure
> app service, you could not leverage this feature, you may need to
> manually add the authentication middleware in your code. When enabling
> authentication in your code, you could get better flexibility and you
> could programmatically initialize the authentication settings.