# OnTokenValidated event not firing when application is deployed as Azure Web App, but fires when running locally

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, openid-connect

I am trying to add some custom claims at runtime from my database.

I've used this article as a basis for my work:
[Add Arbitrary Claims after AzureAd Login](http://winsmarts.com/add-arbitrary-claims-from-sql-server-after-azuread-login-6ffb62af7ecc)

The code works perfectly when I run locally in VS 2019.  I can open multiple incognito windows, sign in different users and each time, the  OnTokenValicated event fires as expected.  The behavior is:

- Azure AD Login
- OnTokenValidated
- Home Page

I've published it as an Azure Web Application, and the event never fires.  After publishing, if I go to the home page of that site, the behavior is:

- Azure AD Login
- Go to home page

I even went so far as to publish the code with a division by zero error (unhandled) which never fires.

I'm at a loss right now, wondering if there is maybe a setting I'm missing in the Azure configuration or something?

Here's a sanitizied version of my code.

```
        services
        .AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
        {
            Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
            options.Events ??= new OpenIdConnectEvents();
            var onTokenValidated = options.Events.OnTokenValidated;
            options.Events.OnTokenValidated = ctx =>
            {

                onTokenValidated?.Invoke(ctx);


                var userId = "";
                if (ctx.Principal.FindFirstValue("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier") != null)
                {
                    userId = ctx.Principal.FindFirstValue("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier");
                }
                else if (ctx.Principal.FindFirstValue("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier") != null)
                {
                    userId = ctx.Principal.FindFirstValue("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier");
                }

                ResponseClass userConfig = AccountDataAccess.GetUserConfig(
                    UserId: userId
                );

                if (userConfig.Success)
                {

                    newClaims.Add(new Claim("SessionId", userConfig.SessionId));
                    newClaims.Add(new Claim("Permission1", userConfig.Permission1));                          

                }

                var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(newClaims);
                ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };

        });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the redirectURL, after you authenticate is correct and works in production? I would look at the logs o figure out why it fails..  do you get an user object in production that is authenticated?

Comment: Hi Tore - I used the video here [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_abaB7494s) and intentionally broke my callback.  I'm not getting that error.  
Which logs would you look at?  Since it's not firing the event code where I expect it to, I'm not sure where to start.

One last thing I noticed:  
In the video, and using local host, the redirect_uri ends looks like  https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc 
But when I look at the link made by my application, it looks like:
https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved from this link:
[whats wrong with my reply url for aad auth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483483/whats-wrong-with-my-reply-url-for-aad-auth)

Like the original poster, I had enabled Azure App Authentication.
I went to my app in the Azure Portal, clicked on Authentication, then clicked on "App Service authentication" and selected "Disable"
Saved and then ran the site again.....SUCCESS!

Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).